# How to automatically create bookmarks in a PDF?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object, javascript-objects

I'm fairly new to Javascript and PDF scripting so hopefully my explanation is clear.

I have a set of around 100 PDFs with approximately 250 pages in each document. I ultimately need to split each of these pages into their own PDF and name them according to a specific ID on each page.

On the every page there is a a phrase that says "License Number: XXXXXX"

I know Adobe has a built in feature that can split PDFs and label them by bookmark, so I've tried to simplify my solution to automatically create and name bookmarks at the location of the ID number.

```
for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {
    for (var n = 0; n < this.getPageNumWords(p); n++) {
        var license = this.getPageNthWord(p, n);
        var number = this.getPageNthWord(p, n + 1);
        var id = this.getPageNthWord(p, n + 2);
        var search = license + " " + number + " " + id;
        var regex = /License Number: [0-9]+/;
        if (regex.test(search)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    this.bookmarkRoot.createChild(search, "pageNum=" + p, p);
}
```

I can get the script to bookmark each page, but it names all of them [object Search]. I'm wondering if anyone has any insight.